# Trying to show image HTML using database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create an animal's database, for an animal shelter. So far, what I have is a set of tables with the animal's species and when the user chooses the species it shows all animals available. Now I want the user to click on the animal chosen and more details about that animal, such has, location, gender, size, will show. Problem is, I know very little about Javascript/ HTML and I am encountering lots of issues. One of them is showing the image in this third screen of more details. What I have so far with HTML is:

```
<div class="row" style="text-align: center">
<img src="foto_animal" height="180">
</div>
```

"foto_animal" is the column in table "Animal" that holds the Image URL. Is there anything I should change with Javascript or is it just a HTML problem? Thanks in advance.

EDIT

I manage to get the URL, this is the script.js file

```
var populateContact = function(data) {
$('#contact_photo').text(data.foto_animal);
```

This is the index.html

```
<h2><span id="contact_photo"></h2>
```

It shows the URL, but now I want it to be recognize as an image.

Comment: You can't point the image's source url to another HTML element, it simply won't load. Any reason why you won't just load the url in the image tag directly?

Comment: What does JavaScript have to do with your issue? To show the image you'd load the path from PHP after pulling it from your db.

Comment: Where is your Javascript code? And what framework are you using for your project? Are you using PHP along with Javascript, or just plain Javascript? Also, If you're new to JS and HTML, you might like to visit w3schools.com first and do some reading to at least know the basics.

Comment: I did, but my time is very limited, so I am using an example from dreamfactory (the website I am using to make API calls). I am using only HTML+JS+CSS; I am doing this way because each animal has its own photo, so I don't need to save the photos inside the img folder, I can have them saved on imgur for example, and just refer to the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : To have your users download the  as requested i nthe comments, try adding a  tag and setting it's download property.

Here is an [example](http://w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp).

---

Via html, when referencing an image in `src` property of the `<img>` tag, add the file extension of your image file

assuming your foto_animal is a jpeg file **and** in the same location with the html files,

`<img id='myImg' src="foto_animal.jpg" height=180px>`

Via javascript,
You simply call the element using document.getElementByID and set the .src property

`document.getElementById("myImg").src = "foto_animal.jpg";`

Via jquery,
Simply use the .attr property to set src of your  tag ID

`$("#myImg").attr('src', 'foto_animal.jpg');`

Comment: The image is being linked. I have an URL. So, foto_animal is a column in the database and the content is something like this: http://i.imgur.com/OrK7thb.jpg 
When you open this link, you'll see a photo, and what I want to do is, instead of saving all the photos on my server, I want to have them being saved somewhere else that I can just refer to them. The part I don't know is if I should do something with my JS files or withe the HTML. They're not being referenced in any JS file, only HTML. Of course I have the function to fetch the data, but that's it.

Comment: Miss, I think you need to study a server side script so you can achieve this. Like `ASP` or `python` or.. well.. `PHP`.  If you insist on using Javascript, there's also `Node.js`. Simply query your image path via stored procedure, then asynchronously give the path to the `src` of the <img> tag.

The procedure is simply too long for a single post. I'm afraid I can only ask you to decide on a script and look up on the thousands of articles available for them online. 

..Please don't forget to upvoe and accept an answer.

Comment: Thanks. My time is very limited for it. I am trying to do this using internet tutorials and online help. So far, so good. But when I get stuck it's REALLY stuck, like right now. But thank you for your help. I am using Node.js to do this. I have the server side for it. So far it works for text data, like the animals's name and notes. But I just can't download images with it. It looks like it's simple, but my knowledge is very limited unfortunately .

Comment: ah... have you tried adding this:  `<a href='(path to your image)'><img...></img></a>` ? this will make it so that when your image is clicked, it will lead to your image so users can download it.

Comment: I now have the answer. Use the `download` property of the <a> tag. Please check this out https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: I updated my question. I can't find information about this, so if I can't do, I will try a different approach. I tried the download way, but the image needs to be stored in my img folder. Which is apparently the easiest way to do this.